# My Full Code for updating single record in visual basic -2015, which shows error?

Tags: vb.net

How to trap "No value given for one or more parameter expression". Here is full code:-

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    '*******************************************************************************************

    BtnSave.Enabled = False : Dbconnection.Close() : Dbconnection.Open()
    LEN = LvMasterAdapter.Fill(MasterDataSet, "LeaveMaster")

    Dim DesInd As Integer
    LvMasterReader = LvMasterCmd.ExecuteReader()


    For I = 0 To LEN - 1

        LvMasterReader.Read()

        If LvMasterReader("Mnt") = CmbMonth.Text And LvMasterReader("Yr") = CmbYear.Text And LvMasterReader("SAP_No") = CInt(TxtSapID.Text) Then

            ' MN = CmbMonth.Text : YRR = CmbYear.Text : LT = CmbLeaveType.Text : SID = CInt(TxtSapID.Text)

            DesInd = LvMasterReader("DesigIndex")

            If LvMasterReader("LeaveStatus") = "N" Then

                Try

                    LvMasterCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE LeaveMaster SET  Sap_No= @Sap_No, From_Date= @From_Date, To_Date= @To_Date, LeaveType= @LeaveType, Days= @Days, LeaveStatus= @LeaveStatus , MNT = @MNT , YR = @YR WHERE Sap_No=  " & CInt(TxtSapID.Text) & " AND MNT=  " & CmbMonth.Text & "  AND YR= " & CmbYear.Text & " ;"

                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sap_No", TxtSapID.Text)

                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From_Date", DtpFrom.Value)
                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To_Date", DtpTo.Value)

                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", CmbLeaveType.Text)
                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", LblDays.Text)

                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNT", CmbMonth.Text)
                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", CmbYear.Text)

                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveStatus", "Y")

                    LvMasterReader.Close()


                    LvMasterCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    LvMasterCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    Exit Sub
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It's interesting - you're iterating over Reader using some outer variable. How do you know how many records you've fetched?

Comment: I don't got your query, I want only one record witch fulfill WHERE clause. Which are the outer variables and where reader iterating ? Please elaborate and help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
'*******************************************************************************************

BtnSave.Enabled = False : Dbconnection.Close() : Dbconnection.Open()
LEN = LvMasterAdapter.Fill(MasterDataSet, "LeaveMaster")

Dim DesInd As Integer
LvMasterReader = LvMasterCmd.ExecuteReader()


For I = 0 To LEN - 1

'Run your test while Datareader reads
 while   LvMasterReader.Read()

    If LvMasterReader("Mnt") = CmbMonth.Text And LvMasterReader("Yr") = CmbYear.Text And LvMasterReader("SAP_No") = CInt(TxtSapID.Text) Then

        ' MN = CmbMonth.Text : YRR = CmbYear.Text : LT = CmbLeaveType.Text : SID = CInt(TxtSapID.Text)

        DesInd = LvMasterReader("DesigIndex")

        If LvMasterReader("LeaveStatus") = "N" Then

            Try

'Still parameterize your "CRITERIA"
'and provide values for them'
'or enclose their values in single quotes - ''
 'LvMasterCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE LeaveMaster SET  Sap_No= @Sap_No, From_Date= @From_Date, To_Date= @To_Date, LeaveType= @LeaveType, Days= @Days, LeaveStatus= @LeaveStatus , MNT = @MNT , YR = @YR WHERE Sap_No=  '" & CInt(TxtSapID.Text) & "' AND MNT=  '" & CmbMonth.Text & "'  AND YR= '" & CmbYear.Text & "' ;"
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                LvMasterCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE LeaveMaster SET  Sap_No= @Sap_No, From_Date= @From_Date, To_Date= @To_Date, LeaveType= @LeaveType, Days= @Days, LeaveStatus= @LeaveStatus , MNT = @MNT , YR = @YR WHERE Sap_No=@old_SapNo  AND MNT=@old_MNT AND YR= @old_YR;"

                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sap_No", TxtSapID.Text)

                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From_Date", DtpFrom.Value)
                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To_Date", DtpTo.Value)

                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", CmbLeaveType.Text)
                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", LblDays.Text)

                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNT", CmbMonth.Text)
                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", CmbYear.Text)

                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveStatus", "Y")

'provide values if you parameterized or comment out the next 3 lines
'if you used the commented Query above
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old_SapNo",CInt(TxtSapID.Text))

     LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old_MNT",CmbMonth.Text)

  LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old_YR",CmbYear.Text)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                LvMasterReader.Close()


                LvMasterCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                LvMasterCmd.Parameters.Clear()
'depending on how many rows..
'if more than one, then comment out 'Exit Sub'
                Exit Sub
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
    End if
   End if
  End While
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Some explanation please, why is this different and how does it help? Otherwise it is just a wall of code that no one is going to read and it will be downvoted.

Comment: I have copied your edited codes, but it shows same error "No Value given for one or more parameter expression..". I am trying to update only single record which fulfill the WHERE criteria. Please help